# How to force logout when following reset password path

Tags: laravel-5

I have a working password reset process with the following routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [], 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token?}', ['as' => 'site.password.showResetForm', 'uses' => 'PasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('/password/email', ['as' => 'site.password.sendResetLinkEmail', 'uses' => 'PasswordController@postEmail']);
    Route::post('/password/reset', ['as' => 'site.password.reset', 'uses' => 'PasswordController@reset']);
});
```

My problem arises if someone is currently already logged in on the machine.  In that case when A user clicks on the link in the email, PasswordController@showResetForm is never executed and the their home page opens in a new tab.  Is there a way to force the current user to be logged out so that the password reset can proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `Auth::logout();` in one of your controllers.

If the `showResetForm` is never displayed due to user being logged in, you will need to create a temporary page where you call the above function and then redirect to Password Reset page:

```
public function do_password_reset()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('PasswordController@showResetForm');
}
```

(Remember to add the relevant route for this function.)

Comment: If you are logged in in Firefox. Request a Reset password email. Open the "reset password" email in chrome, click the link, reset your password. Laravel will try to log you out of chrome, but you will still be logged in in FF and any other browsers.

Comment: This is as expected, `Auth::logout()` only logs you out of current browser. If you want to log user out from all devices, you can delete all the user's session from the `sessions` table (assuming you are using database driver for sessions).

Answer (score 4):

Rather than creating additional routes I overwrote the ***showResetForm*** function used to route the user to the ***auth.password.reset*** view, found in

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php
```

To do so, within your ***ResetPasswordController*** add the following:

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

All being well that should be the only code you need to add.

Comment: I went with the accepted answer, but like this approach better.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As for editing the **ResetPasswordController** suggested by *Lawrence*, you might want to remove guest middleware from it's constructor:

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

This middleware redirects authenticated uses to the root page, so it would prevent an already logged in user from logging out.